# Stage 1 vs Stage 2 in glmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I'm replicating (a subset of) glmer (in Haskell).  And I'm making sure I understand the stage 1 vs. stage 2 bit of the code.

As I understand it, stage 1 uses a numerical optimizer (by default nlopt's BOBYQA) to optimize `theta` by doing gradient-directed steps in `u` and `beta` simultaneously (with that step-halving bit also!).  Then switches to stage 2 (now, by default, using Nelder-Mead) where `theta` and `beta` are optimized numerically-- starting from the stage 1 results--doing the gradient-directed steps in just `u`.  Is that correct?

Is there a simple way to explain the need for stage 2? Either as a general matter of accuracy or in terms of the specific cases where it matters?  I'm trying to decide if I should replicate that part next or move on to using the code as it is now for a bit...

For my test case, my stage 1 only answer is quite close (in terms of `theta` and `beta` and `b`) to the glmer answer.  And I'm assuming (which might be a mistake!) that the remaining differences are from the stage 1 vs. stage 2 bit.  Can I make glmer only do stage 1 so I can compare?

Thanks!

Comment: "Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-Plus" is the first place I would look. Agree with close/migrate vote.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll take a look.